# lighttpd behind pound gets "connection timed out" error when using browser other than Chrome

Tags: centos, wordpress, lighttpd, pound

Please help me diagnose a problem.

I had a working website (WordPress) for the last 6 months working just fine. No updates or new installations have been made in the server.

Today users complain that the website hangs. I usually use Chrome and when I went the site... it worked fine. I used IE, Safari and Firefox and the web site does hang... just keeps loading. I tried on another computer, same thing. I cleared cookies, history, etc. from Chrome and browsed to the site and it still worked. Cleared cookies, history, etc. from IE and still didn't work.

Now this only happens when browsing to the WordPress site, there are other html and PHP files that I can access without any issue. I can even access the WordPress administration site.

I looked at `/var/log/messages` and I see:

```
pound: (7f4985ca9700) error copy server cont: Connection timed out
```

I edit `pound.cfg` to this:

```
User "pound"
Group "pound"
Control "/var/lib/pound/pound.cfg"
Alive 30
Client 120
TimeOut 15
Grace 30
```

and it still times out in 2 minutes (pretty long to load this page, in Chrome it works in less than 15 seconds).

I don't see any errors in `/var/log/lighttpd/error.log`

Have I been hacked?

What else can I look at?

I have restored the WordPress site from a backup but the problem persists.
I have updated to the latest version of WP (3.8.1)... same problem.
Before updating anything I checked if any files had been tempered with (modified date)... nothing new.

I am using CentOS release 6.4 (Final).

Comment: You are running WordPress and NOT keeping it up to date?!

Comment: I updated to the latest version of WP today (3.8.1)... same problem. Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems one of the WordPress plugins was causing conflicts.

I turned them all off and the site started working on all browsers, then I began turning them on one by one.

Fortunately the plugin causing the issue was not being used on the site so I was able to eliminate it.

Do WP plugins update by themselves?

This is strange because no one else has access to the site administration.

The plugin causing the issue was: "***WP Video Lightbox Version 1.6.5***"